# Calling controller methods from inside view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to call a method inside the controller from our view using codeigniter.I know it is a bad practice but, now I force to do this.Thank you

Comment: Can't you just refactor the code that is in your view that you need to reuse and put it someplace else?  Like in your controller for instance?

Comment: It would be interesting to see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Would also like to know what you are trying to do as this would help with the solution

Comment: I need it because I have two views (contract view and invoice) and need the same output from a controllers (contract-invoice) variable in a loop. It seems more logic to have a function in the controller than in the utility helper which is global.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to call a function of the current controller, you have to get the instance of the current controller this way:

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->your_method($param);
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just do:

```
$this->controller_method();
```

*While this might answer your question, I personally agree with the comments of – Matthew J Morrison and DamienL.*

Comment: Don't think this will work, doesn't $this refer to the Loader class inside a view?

Answer (score 4):

in your controller put

```
$data['myClass'] = $this;
```

That way when you send the data to the view, it will load the controller :)

Then you can access the methods like

```
$myClass->method();
```

Answer (score 4):

In controller:

```
$this->method_call =& get_instance();
```

In view

```
$this->method_call->show();
```